# Webpage view on mobile - only top half displays correctly?

Tags: html, mobile

Here is the page I'm working on:
https://glutenfreetravelsite.com/mobile/Rhode-Island/Providence/gluten-free-restaurant/Kabob-and-Curry/3795.php

[image: Screen shot - top review showing proper width, bottom review is too wide]

Looks great in a web browser and on mobile, the first part of the page is fine. But when scrolling down to the second review, the review content doesn't fit into the width of the screen.

I've looked at the html and am comparing the html for the first review and for the second review. I can't figure out why the second review isn't displaying correctly.

I understand the html is old and not up to current standards. However, my objective at this point is to get it displaying correctly with the html that's currently there. I'm sure there must be a , ,  or  tag out of place somewhere but can't figure it out. Can anyone see which tags I need to fix?

I didn't include the source code for the page as I assume it would be easier to view it with a right click on that page.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You put your 2nd paragraph in table. I think that's the main problem. Try to put the paragraph outside the table.
However, if you still want to put your paragraph in there, you should add CSS code to make your table responsive. Try this code:

```
@media
  only screen 
and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) 
and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

tr {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }

    td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 0;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/wXgJww?editors=1100